# Group by date and value

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 columns in a table called `articles`: created_at, articles, keyword and category

I have this query to analyse the data:

```
SELECT DATE(`created_at`) AS date, COUNT(1) AS articles 
FROM articles 
WHERE `keyword`='keyword1' 
GROUP BY DATE(`created_at`)
```

This returns total number of articles per day for one keyword.

I would like to have a total and then break this down and categorise the articles as either `cat1`, `cat2` or `cat3` for each keyword. So giving a table like this:

```
|date|keyword|articles|cat1|cat2|cat3|
```

I can't seem to get this right though, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is the `dataType` of your `created_at` column?

Comment: you need to cast the `DateTime` to `Date` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
DATE(`created_at`),
keyword,
count(*) as TotalCount,
SUM (case when Category = Cat1 then 1 else 0 end) as Cat1Count,
SUM (case when Category = Cat2 then 1 else 0 end) as Cat2Count,
SUM (case when Category = Cat3 then 1 else 0 end) as Cat3Count

from articles
group by DATE(`created_at`), keyword
order by DATE(`created_at`), keyword
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case) as Cat1Count, SUM (case when Category = Cat2 then 1 else 0 end case) as Ca' at line 5

Comment: Try it one more time. I've fixed this statement.

Comment: Adding to this you can simply SUM(Category = "cat1") as Cat1Count.

This is because all boolean operations in MySQL return either 0 or 1. Summing this result allows you to count specific categories in your columns. 

This is the same answer as above however less SQL code.

Comment: Many thanks this worked - I had to remove the space between "SUM (case" . Thanks again.